# How to emit back to parent component after axios.put request?

Tags: vuejs2

A user can view his post (title, message, etc) and choose to edit it by clicking an "Edit Post" button. After the user edits his post (an http PUT request is accomplished), he must be taken back to the updated view of his post.

*My problem is that I don't know how to take him back to the view of his updated post.*

Let me show below **[[also live app demo here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vmyz04jzll)]**

> Here is my `PostDetail.vue` template that shows the details of his
>   post:

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="!editPostFormIsVis">
      <ul>
        <li>ID: {{post.id}}</li>
        <li>Title: {{post.title}}</li>
        <li>Body: {{post.body}}</li>
        <li>userId: {{post.userId}}</li>
      </ul>
      <button @click="editPost">Edit this Post</button>
    </div>
    <div v-if="editPostFormIsVis">
      <h3>Update this Post</h3>
      <EditPost v-bind:post="post"/>
      <button @click="cancelEdit">Cancel Edit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

import axios from "axios";
import EditPost from "@/components/EditPost.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    EditPost
  },
  data() {
    return {
      post: {},
      editPostFormIsVis: false
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + this.$route.params.id
      )
      .then(resp => {
        this.post = resp.data;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  },
  methods: {
    editPost() {
      this.editPostFormIsVis = true;
    },
    cancelEdit() {
      this.editPostFormIsVis = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This is what the above code looks like:
[image]

So he clicks the Edit Post button and he can edit his post. After submission, how can I send the user back so he can view his updated post? I thought I'd try to add something like: `this.$emit('editPostFormIsVis', false)` in my axios .then()

> Here is the `EditPost.vue` template

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Post Id: {{post.id}}</p>
    <form @submit="editPost">
      <label for="titleInput">Title:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="titleInput" v-model="post.title" required>
      <br>
      <label for="bodyInput">Body:</label>
      <br>
      <textarea rows="3" v-model="post.body"></textarea>
      <br>
      <label for="assignSelect">Assign to:</label>
      <br>
      <select id="assignSelect">
        <option value="1">John</option>
        <option value="2">Sam</option>
        <option value="3">Mary</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "PostForm",
  props: {
    post: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  created() {},
  methods: {
    editPost(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      axios
        .put("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + this.post.id)
        .then(response => {
          //dosomething
          console.log(response.status);
          this.$emit('editPostFormIsVis', false)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[Codesandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vmyz04jzll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it could be:

`<EditPost v-bind:post="post" @saved="editPostFormIsVis = false" />`

(or also `v-on:saved="editPostFormIsVis = false"` which is the longer syntax)

The `@saved` directive reacts on "saved" events that are emitted from your component, this can be any name you like.

So inside your `EditPost` component, you would do:

```
someFormSaveMethod() {
  // save stuff using a promise maybe
  .then(() => {
    // Emit a "saved" event.
    this.$emit('saved');
  });
}
```

For more info see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.